# This doesn't happen often:  Why is this JavaScript code only broken in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, markdown, wmd

I've decided that I've fallen in love with the Markdown editor on Stack Overflow.  It's a fork from `showdown.js` from John Fraser.  I want to use this parser on a project of mine, but after analyzing the source, I found that it was a bit messy for my taste.

So I set about modifying the JavaScript code to meet my needs, namely:

1. Getting rid of all the global variables,
2. Combining the variable declarations to a single `var` per scope,
3. Changing concatenation to array joins,
4. various other tweaks intended to make the minified source smaller.

I've got everything working beautifully, except for one small problem:  The autocomplete code in the `command.doList` function is wonky in Chrome.  I've tested everything to work properly in Internet Explorer, FireFox, and Safari.  I've isolated the matter down to the following lines:

```
// Get the item prefix - e.g. " 1. " for a numbered list, " - " for a bulleted
// list.
getItemPrefix = function () {
    var prefix;
    if (isNumberedList) {
        // the `s` variable is just a string space.
        prefix = [s, num, '. '].join('');
        num++;
    } else {
        prefix = [s, bullet, s].join('');
    }
    return prefix;
};

// Fixes the prefixes of the other list items.
getPrefixedItem = function (itemText) {
    // The numbering flag is unset when called by autoindent.
    if (isNumberedList === undefined) {
        isNumberedList = /^\s*\d/.test(itemText);
    }

    // Renumber/bullet the list element.
    // THE FOLLOWING LINES COMMENTED OUT TO FIX A BUG.
    //itemText = itemText.replace(/^[ ]{0,3}([\*\+\-]|\d+[.])\s/gm,
        // function () { return getItemPrefix(); });
    return itemText;
};
```

The two commented-out lines near the end stop Chrome from behaving wonky, but numbered lists no longer auto-increment.  As soon as I un-comment the lines, all major browsers begin working normally, except for Chrome.  (Chrome goes crazy and auto-completes the list with extra numbering and bullets, also happens when trying to use an unordered list.)

The problem obviously doesn't exist *here* on Stack Overflow, so I'm hoping it's just a stupid oversight on my part.  (Either that or Stack Overflow has updated and fixed the bug.)

Comment: @indieinvader In the same scope as the two functions.  Right above it is something along the lines of:  `var getItemPrefix, getPrefixedItem, num = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [fix](https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/wmd/blob/c7889e92dd00227da17c5fede8075bb56503e94b/src/js/chunk.js) for another WMD fork (line 32).

Comment: Well, look at that.  And I thought it was just me!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to backslash the *+- in square brackets, should you? That might be what Chrome is having problems with.

Comment: at least you don't in regexes in other languages, not sure about javascript

Comment: Hmmm.  JSLint was arguing with me about it, so I added it in.  Let me give it a shot without them.

Comment: the "-" might cause a problem in the middle but not at the end.

Comment: Removed them.  Got the same behavior.  Still works in other browsers.